# Emacs tramp to edit remote files on Windows from Linux

Tags: windows, linux, emacs, tramp

What is the best way to edit remote files on a Windows box (XP) from Linux?

I am running emacs 23.3 locally under Linux.

I would like to keep the extra software on the windows-box minimal, but I can install some extra software if needed. Cygwin is already there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If cygwin is already there, running a `sshd` in the windows machine and using Tramp (maybe using the `scp` method) is the best option to my knowledge.

Comment: thanks, I was unaware of the built-in sshd in cygwin. It works now

Comment: /scpc:userid@hostname:/c/path/file works great for me from Emacs 23.3.1 on Ubuntu Linux connecting to a Windows 7 host and cygwin sshd